# how to do upload image within steps method in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

```
     List<Step> steps = [    
      Step(
      isActive: false,
      state: StepState.editing,
      title: const Text('Id Proof'),
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
         OutlineButton(
         onPressed: chooseImage,
         child: Text('Choose Image'),),
         showImage(),            
         OutlineButton(
         onPressed: startUpload,
         child:Text(Upload Image),
         ),
      Text(status,textAlign:TextAlign.center,style:TextStyle(color:Colors.green))
        ],
      ),
    ),  
  ];
```

Unable to initialize chooseImage, showImage, startUpload. I have tried to initiate above the steps starting. showing errors

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Answer (score 0):

chooseImage & startUpload are not functions, if you created a function

```
void chooseImage() {
 // add image picking code here
}
```

then you need to change

```
onPressed: chooseImage,
```

to

```
onPressed: chooseImage(),
```

if you didn't make those functions you could also do

```
onPressed: () {
// add image picking code here
}
```